# Why is HMAC truncated in IPsec?

Tags: hmac, ipsec

I'm having a look at IPsec standard and I realized that integrity and data authentication check is based on 96-bit truncated version of HMAC algorithms. For example, in IPsec v3 we can use HMAC-MD5-96, HMAC-SHA-1-96, AES-XCBC-MAC-96. What is the reason behind this choice?

Comment: What RFCs have you checked so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer to this check out [RFC 2104](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt), em mine:

> A well-known practice with message authentication codes is to
>   truncate the output of the MAC and output only part of the bits
>   (e.g., [MM, ANSI]).  Preneel and van Oorschot [PV] show some
>   analytical advantages of truncating the output of hash-based MAC
>   functions. The results in this area are not absolute as for the
>   overall security advantages of truncation. **It has advantages (less
>
>   information on the hash result available to an attacker)** and
>   disadvantages (less bits to predict for the attacker).  Applications
>   of HMAC can choose to truncate the output of HMAC by outputting the t 
>   leftmost bits of the HMAC computation for some parameter t (namely,
>   the computation is carried in the normal way as defined in section 2
>   above but the end result is truncated to t bits). We recommend that
>   the output length t be not less than half the length of the hash
>   output (to match the birthday attack bound) and not less than 80 bits 
>   (a suitable lower bound on the number of bits that need to be
>   predicted by an attacker).  We propose denoting a realization of HMAC 
>   that uses a hash function H with t bits of output as HMAC-H-t. For
>   example, HMAC-SHA1-80 denotes HMAC computed using the SHA-1 function
>   and with the output truncated to 80 bits.  (If the parameter t is not 
>   specified, e.g. HMAC-MD5, then it is assumed that all the bits of the 
>   hash are output.)

Truncation also reduces the amount of data transmitted over the wire so bandwidth requirements are reduced.